# How to merge two menu managed separately in wordpress for displaying as one in front end theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wp theme for a site which is already built on wp, and having very large menu which is divided into two menu in wp admin.

I want to merge this two menu in theme in single UL. Currently it generates two menu in different div container and ul li, and is breaking the styles & js applied on it.

How can i merge this two menu into single ul li in single container?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ok, so if you are using the wp_nav_menu()

try using something like

```
<ul id="MyMenu">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'FirstMenu', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'SecondMenu', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
</ul>
```

using the items_wrap will remove the ul from each menu, so encapsulate the menu in an already defined ul tag, the wp_nav_menu will spit out just li tags.

See Removing the ul wrap: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

M

Comment: I have already tried this, but this doesn't seems to work. I'm using roots theme.

Comment: can you post the code use to generate the wp_nav_menu?
ie: register_nav_menus( array( 'FirstMenu' => 'Menu1', 'SecondMenu' => 'Menu2' )); and also post the code youre trying to use. i know this method will work, im currently using it on another site.

Comment: this seems to be a answer, but not working with the roots theme, may be something is wrong with the theme or custom code we have done. Need to check it.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that each **wp_nav_menu** is still being wrapped in individual div's. 
You need to turn off those div's as well, by adding **"'container' => false"** to each one, like so:

```
<ul id="MyMenu">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'FirstMenu', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'container' => false ) ); ?>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'SecondMenu', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'container' => false ) ); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine them with this method. It keeps some of the menu classes generated by WP.

```
// two WordPress menus combined into one.
// first menu.
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'=> 'secondary', // or whatever location
    'fallback_cb'   => false,
    'container'     => '',
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
    'echo' => false
) );
// include all of the menu items from the first inside the second menu.
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary', // or whatever location
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s ' . $menu . '</ul>',
) );
```