# Wordpress insert custom menu in primary menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu

I may be complicating a bit, but if this would be possible it would solve my problem :)
I have a primary menu and language menu that i need to merge.
Adding elements to my primary menu is not a problem:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_element', 10, 2);
    function add_element($items, $args){
      if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
        $items .= '<li id="appended_li"></li>';
      }
    return $items;
    }
```

This adds li tag to my primary menu.
Now I would like to insert my language menu in my primary menu. Something like this:

```
  add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_element', 10, 2);
   function add_element($items, $args){
     if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
      $items .= '<li id="appended_li>';
      $items .= wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'mobile-language-switcher'));
      $items .= '</li>';
   }
   return $items;
  }
```

Now this doesn't work as desired.I get:

```
<div class="mobile-language-switcher"></div>
<div class="my_menu">
  <li>smth</li>
  <li>smth else</li>
  <li id="appended_li"></li>
</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="my_menu">
  <li>smth</li>
  <li>smth else</li>
  <li id="appended_li"><div class="mobile-language-switcher"></div></li>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this one correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem here: [How to merge two menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346668/how-to-merge-two-menu-managed-separately-in-wordpress-for-displaying-as-one-in-f)

The easy way was to strip the wrapper and call wp_nav_menus in header.php